# jQuery: Self Executing Plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am working on expansion of my jQuery plug-in authoring knowledge, just playing around with my own ideas for learning benefits. So i was wondering how you guys tackle the need of plugin executing without any user specific input.

So I have a need for plug-in that executes right away after document is ready, without any user's specific input just as long as doc is loaded, so the only way I see how to execute plug-in on it's own is to attach handler to ready listener that executes my function which I extended the jQuery with. And because this needs to be self enclosed, part of the code, I attach handler to event listener within the function.

So how else could one tackle this? Any take at this is appreciated. Thank you in advance everyone.

Comment: Is there a specific reason that your script needs to be considered a "plugin" at all? A "self-executing plugin" semantically implies more of an application (script) than a tool (plugin).

Comment: good point JasonWyatt. well the way i look at this is that it is semi plugin-app. it executes certain logic right away by it self if here is no overwriting of default options, and you can overwrite options, including the time it should be executed and based on what ever user input/action is required and what it actually iterates through. So i cant really classify it as application, it a hybrid more then anything, unless i am wrong.

Comment: i see this was rather time wasting then exploring topic : (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     function_that_starts_your_plugin();
});
```

within the .js file that contains your plugin. As long as the appropriate <script> tag loads the .js file, then your code will get started automatically. If you want the option to change options on a per-page basis, or disable completely, put some sentinel variables in another javascript block before the one that loads your plugin:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var mypluginAutoRun = FALSE;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugin.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you Marc B, no pun intended, but that's exactly how I do that right now. I am not sure what exactly pushed me to post this topic. Probably hoping in turn to learn of other ways.